# Why is this code not working? (combining two test functions)

Tags: haskell

```
module Data where

data Cons a = Con (a -> Bool)
   deriving (Show)           

twoCons :: Cons a -> Cons a -> Cons a
twoCons (Con a) (Con b) = Con (twoCons' a b)

twoCons' :: (a -> Bool) -> (a -> Bool) -> (a -> Bool)
twoCons' c1 c2 x = (c1 x) && (c2 x)
```

This code doesn't work, with or without `deriving (Show)`.

It's supposed to combine two tests/constraints and return a function wrapped by the third `Con`.
The constraints might be `(>1)` and `(<10)`, the outcome should be an combination of the two constraints, the type of constraint can be anything.

Comment: What do you mean by "this doesn't work"? If it doesn't compile, tell us the error message. If it compiles but gives the wrong result, tell us what values give you the wrong result, tell us that wrong result, and tell us what you expected instead.

Comment: nvm I think I got it to work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that there is no reasonable way to write an instance of `Show` for `Cons` (try it yourself!)

If you remove the `deriving (Show)` clause your code works perfectly.

Comment: Further, the body of the constructor Cons is a functional type `(a -> Bool)`. You can only derive Show for first-order types such as Int, Bool, String, list, pair and combinations thereof.